# $ajax method does not execute for external javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

very stupidly question I think, When I put this code inline  then works, but when I put it on external js file it can not debug after the $ajax method.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",       
    url: 'WebService/Common/Bank.asmx/GetBank',
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {


        debugger;   ///debug point not reach here

        $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
            $("#ddlLCMasterBank").append($("<option></option>").val(value.BankID1).html(value.BankName1));
        });




    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: so your error handler is getting called?

Comment: You getting any error in the console?

Comment: what is the returned value?

Comment: You did put that in a .js that is included **after** the jQuery .js, right?

Comment: @jcaron Yes I put it afer jquery.js

Comment: @ArunPJohny $ajax code does not execute

Comment: how are you calling it? Is it in a function? What triggers the function?